# Find files recursively, but choose largest from among those with duplicate names

Tags: files, recursive, deduplication

Given a nested directory structure containing various files, I would like to find all the files within it, but where there are multiple files with the same name, I'd like to return just the largest file.

So, for example, given a directory structure like:

```
|--- foo.jpg (110 KB)
|--- bar.jpg (210 KB)
|--- dir
      |----- foo.jpg (860 KB)
      |----- baz.jpg (200 KB)
```

I'd like to produce the output lines (order unimportant):

```
bar.jpg
dir/foo.jpg
dir/baz.jpg
```

How can I do this, preferably from bash?

Comment: What do you need this for? Whatever you want to solve with this, I'm pretty sure there is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @michas -- my use case was that I had previously used wget to download images from a blog, but sometimes the same image had been downloaded in different resolutions, but the file name ended up the same. I wanted to deduplicate, favouring the largest copy of each. But I'm also interested in how you would solve this type of problem at the command-line.

Comment: Vague handwave: `find -printf` to list all files, also printing their sizes, possibly splitting basename and dir, then `sort` on the size, then `sort` on the basename, and then see if `uniq` can look at single fields only or else use `awk`, and then reassemble dirname and basename.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thanks for the hint, I've fleshed it out as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A files
for f (**/*(D.oL)) files[$f:t]=$f
printf '%s\n' $files
```

Would work whatever bytes or characters (like space, newline...) the file names may contain.

With GNU tools:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s/%f/%P\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zt/ -uk2,2 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  cut -d/ -f3- |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

If you want to remove the duplicates, with `zsh`:

```
allfiles=(**/*(D.oL))
typeset -A best
for f ($allfiles) best[$f:t]=$f
bestfiles=($best)
dups=(${allfiles:|bestfiles})
rm -rf -- $dups
```

Description of some zsh features:

- `typeset -A best`: declares an associative array variable like in ksh93. Recent versions of `bash` support it as well.
- `**/*`: recursive globbing. Introduced by zsh in the early nineties, now found in in a few other shells with variations.
- `(D.oL)`: globbing qualifiers. Another zsh invention, not copied yet by other shells though it's an essential companion to recursive  globbing. Used to further qualify the glob. `D` to include dot files, `.` to only include *regular* files, `oL` to order by length (size in bytes).
- `${file:t}`: like in (t)csh, expands to the *tail* part of a filename (the basename).
- `${a:|b}` expands to the elements of `a` that are not in `b`. (*a - b*).

Answer (score 2):

Fleshing out @UlrichSchwarz's comment, I ended up with:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %P %f\n" | sort -k3,3 -k1,1rn | uniq -f 2 | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

**Edit** this won't handle filenames with (for example) spaces in. See @StéphaneChazelas' solution for something more robust.

Comment: I was thinking of a awk program, but your pipes make senses.

Comment: I tried it but it does not show the expected output

Comment: @Begueradj How so?